# How to give style in left nav bar button in iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I added 2 button with images in top left navigation bar. But I am getting problem in its style. Here is my screenshot of button. And this is code of button which I have written in application.

```
UIView *viewButtons = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 32)];

UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,40,35);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"remainder.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sortByremainder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[viewButtons addSubview:button1];


UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button2.frame=CGRectMake(45,0,60,35);
[button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"like_symbol.jpg"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(sortByMostFaved) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[viewButtons addSubview:button1];
[viewButtons addSubview:button2];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:viewButtons];
[viewButtons release];
```

[image]

But i want my button style should be like this image. I want to keep images in button but below screen is more specific with button. It has border and convex area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use grayscale images and that would look better. See example like attached.

> [image]

[image]

[image]

You need to use UIBarButtonItem and set this type of images in that and that assign that UIBarButtonItem to self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.

Also, Use BarButtonItemStyle Border like below so you will get as you want.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnSetting = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(setting:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSetting;
```

Comment: Can UIBarButton be added with UIView ([viewButtons addSubview:button1];
)?

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think so. but why you want to add it in view ?